TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' with make_column_selector
I am trying to perform some preprocessing on my data for a sales prediction. I used make_column_selector to select specific columns in order to apply different encoders to different column. I was trying to create a make selector column object to access column in the feature variable X. it works well for the numerical columns but the category column are the ones giving issues. Every time I use the selector object to select column in the data for the category, I get TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
enter image description here
# set the seed
seed = 200

# set the feature and target variable
X = bigmart_copy.drop('Item_Outlet_Sales', axis = 1)
y = bigmart_copy.Item_Outlet_Sales

# split data into train and test set
X_train, X_temp, y_train, y_temp = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, shuffle = True, random_state=seed)

# create a list of numerical column
num_selector = make_column_selector(dtype_exclude='object')

# create two set of of category list, one of ordinal type and 
# the other of nominal type
cat_selector_ord = ['Item_Fat_Content', 'Outlet_Size', 'Item_MRP_Category', 'Outlet_location_type']
cat_selector_nom = [x for x in bigmart_copy.columns if x not in cat_selector_ord]

cat_selector_nom_nom = make_column_selector(pattern=cat_selector_nom)
cat_selector_ord_ord = make_column_selector(pattern=cat_selector_ord)

# sekect this column from the data
num_cols = num_selector(X)
cat_cols_ord = cat_selector_ord_ord(X)

few rows of adata
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[29], line 27
     25 # sekect this column from the data
     26 num_cols = num_selector(X)
---> 27 cat_cols_ord = cat_selector_ord_ord(X)
     28 cat_cols_nom = cat_selector_nom_nom(X)
     30 # initiate the preprocessor for each selctor

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

I was expecting no error to be present and expect that the code work as expected.

To make sure others able to help you, please add minimal working example so others can run your code. For example, you can print your data, like bigmart_copy.head().

The docstring for pattern says it should be a single string, and doesn't accept a list of strings. If you already have the lists of columns, why do you want to use make_column_selector anyway?

I have later gotten a fix for it by using the columns list. Thanks everyone for the input
